# Normal distribution question about the sentence "recorded to the nearest half-centimeter"

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Question:**

The heights of 1000 students are normally distributed with a mean of 174.5 centimeters and a standard deviation of 6.9 centimeters. **Assuming that the heights are recorded to the nearest half-centimeter**, how many of these students would you expect to have heights:

(a) less than 160.0 centimeters?

(b) equal to 175.0 centimeters?

My problem is, what does the bold sentence mean?

**Attempt**:

$$X \sim N(174.5,6.9^2)$$
So for (a): $$P(X<160) = \phi(\frac{160-174.5}{6.9}) = \phi(-2.1) $$
and for (b), the probability is 0.

But I have found some solutions on the internet not using for example, "160" but 159.75, and for (b), they used $174.5<x<175.5$. Which is related to the bold sentence in the question I assume. So which is the correct way, and why they subtracted / added 0.25?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It means exactly what it says: for instance $159.8$ is recorded as $160.0$, so when computing values of the CDF you have to take this into account for the bounds. Thus a) is not $P(X<160)$ (close but not the right bound), and b) is not zero.

Comment: Oh I got it. Thanks @Jean-ClaudeArbaut